# C# Console Application Program to find Small and Large values

Tags: c#

**I am new to Programming** and I want to write a C# Console Application in which a **user input at-least four or more numbers** (e.g. 5,2,45,39...) and the **Application tells the smaller and greater** (i.e. 2<5<39<45... or something like this).

I was trying if/else conditions but this was written for 3 inputs, **for more than 3 inputs the program became too long** due to if/else conditions.

```
{
        double A, B, C;

        Console.WriteLine("input Three Numbers and Press Enter after each.");
        A = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        B = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        C = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        if (A < B && B < C)
            Console.WriteLine(A + " < " + B + " < " + C);
        else if (A < C && C < B)
            Console.WriteLine(A + " < " + C + " < " + B);
        else if (B < A && A < C)
            Console.WriteLine(B + " < " + A + " < " + C);
        else if (B < C && C < A)
            Console.WriteLine(B + " < " + C + " < " + A);
        else if (C < A && A < B)
            Console.WriteLine(C + " < " + A + " < " + B);
        else if (C < B && B < A)
            Console.WriteLine(C + " < " + B + " < " + A);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c#, you can use `sort` method to sort the array. `Array.Sort` orders elements in an array. It handles different types of elements, including strings and ints.

```
int[] values = { 5, 2, 45, 39 };
Array.Sort(values);
foreach (int value in values)
{
    Console.Write(value);
    Console.Write('<');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. If you're using a List for your values, you can use the extension Min and Max for List<>.

```
        List<int> intList = new List<int>();
        intList.Add(1);
        intList.Add(-1);
        intList.Add(3);
        intList.Add(7);
        intList.Add(4);
        int minValue = intList.Min();
        int maxValue = intList.Max();
```

If you're using an array you've also these extension methods:

```
        int[] intArray = new int[] { 1, -1, 3, 7, 4 };
        int minValue = intArray.Min();
        int maxValue = intArray.Min();
```

Just remember to add the using System.Linq;

Comment: I guess that's not exactly the answer to that question.

Comment: Sorry, I realized later that he doesn't want the min and the max, as he explain in the question (_Application tells the smaller and greater_), he wants the ordered list. Lists have also the Sort() method.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question, the program you are trying to solve can be resolved by applying one of the Sorting Algorithm(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

There are several way of solving this particular problem such as Bubble sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), Heap sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) etc.

I would suggest you to go through all the above shown algorithms and do an in depth study before finalizing your solution.

Since you are new to programming, applying the above algorithms with your own program will help you in learning a lot.

By the way, C# provides an automatic predefined function called **Array.Sort(numbers)** for sorting.

Comment: I'll read them, Thanks alot sir for your guidance. What do you say about C# as first programming language? Do i need to know some thing from C and C++?

Comment: Its fine. Continue learning c#. There is no best way of learning.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with your help. Thanks to all.

```
{
        double A, B, C, D;
        Console.WriteLine("input Four Numbers and Press Enter after each.");
        A = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        B = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        C = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        D = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        double[] values = { A, B, C, D };
        Array.Sort(values);
        int count = 1;
        foreach (double value in values)
        {
            Console.Write(value + " ");
            if (count != values.Length)
            {
                Console.Write("< ");
            }
            count++;
        }
```